# Handling "?" character passed to ZSH function

Tags: zsh, zshrc, zsh-alias

I'm having problem with setting up simple function in ZSH.

I want to make function which downloads only mp3 file from youtube.

I used youtube-dl and i want to make simple function to make that easy for me

```
ytmp3(){
  youtube-dl -x --audio-format mp3 "$@"}
```

So when i try

```
ytmp3 https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=_DiEbmg3lU8
```

i get

```
zsh: no matches found: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=_DiEbmg3lU8
```

but if i try

```
ytmp3 "https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=_DiEbmg3lU8"
```

it works.
I figured out that program runs (but wont download anything) if i remove all charachers after  ?  including it. So i guess that this is some sort of special character for zsh.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The question mark is part of ZSH's pattern matching, similarly to *. It means "Any character".

For instance, `ls c?nfig` will list both "config" and "cinfig", provided they exist.

So, yes, your problem is simply that zsh is trying to interpret the ? in the URL as a pattern to match to files, failing to find any, and crapping out. Escape the ? with a \ or put quotes around it, like you did, to fix it.

Comment: I found a kind of way around
I made a script that open bash shell interpreter and i just parse whole link into that. It's kind of linked bash function.

Thanks for the answer! (i cant upvote my rep is to low)

Answer (score 3):

By default, the ZSH will try to "glob" patterns that you use on command lines (it will try to match the pattern to file names). If it can't make a match, you get the error you're getting (*"no matches found"*).

You can disable this behaviour by disabling the `nomatch` option:

```
unsetopt nomatch
```

The manual page describes this option as follows (it describes what happens when the option is *enabled*):

> If a pattern for filename generation has no  matches,  print  an error,  instead  of  leaving  it unchanged in the argument list.

Try again with the option disabled:

```
$ unsetopt nomatch
$ ytmp3 https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=_DiEbmg3lU8
```

If you want to permanently disable the option, you can add the disable command to your `~/.zshrc` file.